# I can't see data I have added using forms on database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL to add data to a database. When I add data to a form and submit the data I get a message saying the data has been successfully added. However when I view the database on phpMyAdmin all I see is a blank row with nothing in it!

The database is for storing new partners of the company

Here is the code.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

if (isset($_POST["newpartner-submit"])) {
    
    $typeofpartner = $_POST["TypeofPartner"];
    $orgname = $_POST["OrganaizatoinName"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $Address = $_POST["Address"];
    $focalftastaff = $_POST["focalftastaff"];
    $principalname = $_POST["PrincipalName"];
    $Telephone = $_POST["Telephone"];
    $Email = $_POST["npEmail"];
    $Interests = $_POST["biginput1"];
    $IndicateOrpotunities = $_POST["biginput2"];
    $IndicatePartnership = $_POST["biginput3"];
    $specify = $_POST["biginput4"];
    $listkeychallenges = $_POST["biginput5"];
    $partnershipAgreement = $_POST["PartnershipAgreementinplace"];
    $Implementationdate = $_POST["implementationperiod"];
    $agreementavailable = $_POST["PartnerAgrementAvailable"];

    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once 'nptfunctions.inc.php';

    if (emptyInputnewpartner($typeofpartner, $orgname, $location, $Address, $focalftastaff, $principalname, $Telephone, $Email, $Interests, $IndicateOrpotunities, $IndicatePartnership, $specify, $listkeychallenges) !== false) {
        header("location: ../php/newpartner.php?error=emptyInput");
        exit();
    }
    if (invalidAddress($Address) !== false) {
        header("location: ../php/newpartner.php?error=invalidAddress");
        exit();
    }
    if (invalidTelephone($Telephone) !==false) {
        header("location: ../php/newpartner.php?error=invalidTelephoneNumber");
        exit();
    }
    if (invalidnptEmail($Email) !== false) {
        header("location: ../php/newpartner.php?error=invalidEmail");
        exit();
    }

    createnpt($conn, $typeofpartner, $orgname, $location, $Address, $focalftastaff, $principalname, $Telephone, $Email, $Interests, $IndicateOrpotunities, $IndicatePartnership, $specify, $listkeychallenges, $partnershipAgreement, $Implementationdate, $agreementavailable);

}else {
    header("location: ../php/newpartner.php");
    exit();
}
```

dbh.inc.php code

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbname = "fta pms";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

nptfunctions.inc.php code

```
<?php

function emptyInputnewpartner($typeofpartner, $orgname, $location, $Address, $focalftastaff, $principalname, $Telephone, $Email, $Interests, $IndicateOrpotunities, $IndicatePartnership, $specify, $listkeychallenges) {
    $result = null;
    if (empty($typeofpartner) || empty($orgname) || empty($location) || empty($Address) || empty($focalftastaff) || empty($principalname) || empty($Telephone) || empty($Email) ||empty($Interests) || empty($IndicateOrpotunities) || empty($IndicatePartnership) || empty($specify) || empty($listkeychallenges)) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidAddress($Address) {
    $result = null;
    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $Address)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidTelephone($Telephone) {
    $result = null;
    if (!is_numeric($Telephone)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidnptEmail($Email) {
    $result = null;
    if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function createnpt($conn, $typeofpartner, $orgname, $location, $Address, $focalftastaff, $principalname, $Telephone, $Email, $Interests, $IndicateOrpotunities, $IndicatePartnership, $specify, $listkeychallenges, $partnershipAgreement, $Implementationdate, $agreementavailable){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newpartner (typeofpartner, orgname, location, Address, focalftastaff, principalname, Telephone, Email, Interests, IndicateOrpotunities, IndicatePartnership, specify, listkeychallenges, partnershipAgreement, Implementationdate, agreementavailable) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location: ../php/newpartner.php?error=stmtFailed");
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssssssssss", $typeofpartner, $orgname, $location, $Address, $focalftastaff, $principalname, $Telephone, $Email, $Interests, $IndicateOrpotunities, $IndicatePartnership, $specify, $listkeychallenges, $partnershipAgreement, $Implementationdate, $agreementavailable);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location: ../php/newpartner.php?error=none");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Terminology! There is no such thing as a `phpMyAdmin` database. That is a tool written in PHP

Comment: I would suggest using table names with spaces in them like `$dbname = "fta pms";`

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.